# Form Submit with a href

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account",FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, id = "ExternalLoginForm" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset id="socialLoginList">
        <legend></legend>

        @foreach (AuthenticationClientData p in Model)
        {
            <button style="width:100px;" type="submit" name="provider" class="btn_1" value="@p.AuthenticationClient.ProviderName" title="Log in using your @p.DisplayName account">@p.DisplayName</button>

        }


    </fieldset>
    }
```

above form works fine with submit button element. i want to replace the submit button with below.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('ExternalLoginForm').submit()" class="btn btn-primary" id="provider">
               <i class="icon-facebook"></i>

            </a>
```

form submit works fine with above code but the value is not passed in form submit.

> Ex: in submit button posted form contains "Provider" parameter
>   with the value of @p.AuthenticationClient.ProviderName

How can i pass this parameter with a href element?

Comment: try using `onClick="document.getElementById('ExternalLoginForm').submit()"`

Comment: Firstly you need to store `foreach` input values in an array..